# Selecting colums based on row values

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to subset columns (using a dplyr friendly method if possible) based on values in the rows.

The data frame looks like this but with more columns:

```
df <- 
data.frame(a = c("a","b","c","bingo"),
b = c("d","e","a","b"),
c = c("bingo","bingo","a","e"))
```

I want to select only columns that contains the value "bingo"
something like

```
df %>% select(columns_that_contain("bingo"))
```

The expected output:

```
     a     c
1     a bingo
2     b bingo
3     c     a
4 bingo     e
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select-helpers` i.e. `starts_with/ends_with/contains/matches` are doing the match on the column names to `select` the columns.  If we need to match values in a column, use `where` inside `select` and create a logical condition i.e. `'bingo' %in% .` where `.` is the value of individual column and this returns a single TRUE/FALSE as the lhs of `%in%` is an element of length 1.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
      select(where(~ 'bingo' %in% .))
```

Or another option is `any`

```
df %>%
    select(where(~ any(. == 'bingo')))
```

Comment: I am so sorry dear Arun, didn't see your answer as I was typing my own.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR There is no need for sorry.  Yours is a different solution  as it matches also substring.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  select(where(~ any(str_detect(.x, "bingo"))))

      a     c
1     a bingo
2     b bingo
3     c     a
4 bingo     e
```